# Editing the registration e-mail on IPS Board 3.4.5?

Tags: user-registration, ipb

Apologies if this is a dumb question but I've been made an admin on an IPS board version 3.4.5. Most admin things can be worked out (after lots of trial and error!) but I can't find out how to edit the registration e-mail that goes out (registration was closed for some time; I *think* I have re-enabled it).

I've set the board to use e-mail verification then admin approval... but can't find anywhere to actually edit the e-mail that goes out to people when they first register.

I don't know code but can copy & paste proficiently!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Took me a while to figure it out too. Go to System>System settings>Email set-up then you can change the email there. Hope that helped!